# Commerce price attributes doesn't work when I use commerce discount for products

Tags: commerce

I used commerce pricing attributes in order to add extra fee based on a select box field. For example if user select black from color attributes, price increases 10$ and if user select white, price increases 5$ today, I have installed [commerce discount](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_discount) module and defined a discount for all products.

But it seems price attributes doesn't work when discount is defined for product. Because by changing color in no change happened for price.

what is your suggestion to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution of this problem. In order to avoid this error, you must set order for your discount.

for the field order (with description : Discounts will be sorted by this value to be evaluated in that order.)
set the discount on 1 (or the lowest amount in the select box)

this will fix the problem.